# Sort an xml file by tag text using Python

Tags: python, xml, sorting

I have an xml file like this:

```xml
<annotation>

        <object>
        <name>medium</name>
        <pose>Left</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>267</xmin>
            <ymin>273</ymin>
            <xmax>415</xmax>
            <ymax>324</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>medium</name>
        <pose>Left</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>105</xmin>
            <ymin>229</ymin>
            <xmax>261</xmax>
            <ymax>292</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>

</annotation>
```

I want to sort this xml using text of ymin tag in ascending order.
I'm trying this with the following code, which throws ***'NoneType' object is not iterable***.

```py
def getkey(elem):
    return elem.findtext("ymin")

tree = ET.parse("Train/5.xml")
container = tree.find("bndbox")           
container[:] = sorted(container, key=getkey)
```

I want the second object tag to appear in place of the first object tag in the final result.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: show your initial code

Comment: I edit my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With use of `BeautifulSoup`:

```
data = '''

<annotation>

        <object>
        <name>medium</name>
        <pose>Left</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>267</xmin>
            <ymin>273</ymin>
            <xmax>415</xmax>
            <ymax>324</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>medium</name>
        <pose>Left</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>105</xmin>
            <ymin>229</ymin>
            <xmax>261</xmax>
            <ymax>292</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>

</annotation>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
soup.annotation.contents = sorted(soup.annotation.select('object'), key=lambda k: int(k.select_one('ymin').text))


# For XML pretty print, sorted XML is inside `soup`
from xml.dom import minidom
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(str(soup)).toprettyxml(indent="  ").replace('\n\n', '').strip()
print(xmlstr)
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<annotation>
  <object>
        <name>medium</name>
        <pose>Left</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>105</xmin>
            <ymin>229</ymin>
            <xmax>261</xmax>
            <ymax>292</ymax>
          </bndbox>
      </object>
  <object>
        <name>medium</name>
        <pose>Left</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>267</xmin>
            <ymin>273</ymin>
            <xmax>415</xmax>
            <ymax>324</ymax>
          </bndbox>
      </object>
</annotation>
```

EDIT (With reading/writing from/to XML file):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('file.xml', 'r') as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), 'xml')

soup.annotation.contents = sorted(soup.annotation.select('object'), key=lambda k: int(k.select_one('ymin').text))


# For XML pretty print, sorted XML is inside `soup`
from xml.dom import minidom
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(str(soup)).toprettyxml(indent="  ").replace('\n\n', '').strip()

with open('file_out.xml', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(xmlstr)
```

Comment: Hi, I haven't data text, I have an xml file, how can I send my file.xml into BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')?

Comment: I found this error `Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?` .  I install library using  pip install beautifulsoup4

Comment: Hi, tnks for answer, it works. But, how can I save this new xml in a file? I try with newfile = `open('xml_sorted/5.xml', 'wb')  newfile.write(xmlstr)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: with your code I receve this error:` 'NoneType' object is not callable `

Comment: @FrancescoBocci I updated my answer. See the last part of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iter` to search 'ymin' recursively, then `clear` the existing objects and re-add the sorted list of `object`s:

```
objects = sorted(tree.findall('object'),
                 key=lambda object_node: int(next(object_node.iter('ymin')).text))

tree.clear()
tree.extend(objects)

print(ET.tostring(tree))
```

Outputs

```
<annotation>
    <object>
        <name>medium</name>
        <pose>Left</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>105</xmin>
            <ymin>229</ymin>
            <xmax>261</xmax>
            <ymax>292</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>medium</name>
        <pose>Left</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>267</xmin>
            <ymin>273</ymin>
            <xmax>415</xmax>
            <ymax>324</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Comment: Hi, tnks for answer, using tree.clear() I have this error `Instance of 'ElementTree' has no 'clear' member`

Comment: For me, tree is this: `tree = ET.parse("Train/5.xml")`